# Libre Office writer: How to NOT print comments?

Tags: libreoffice, templates, libreoffice-writer, default-settings, comments

A couple of months ago I started using comments in some documents, and it was useful to create PDFs of these pages with these comments in the margins.

However, for some reason now LibreOffice takes *'print comments in margin'* as the default setting, even if the document has no comments.

This means that when I go to print a document (to a PDF writer, but the actual printer is irrelevant) with no comments, the document is squeezed into about 75% of the page, to make space for non-existent comments!

The option to print with no comments is greyed out, so for every page without comments that I want to turn into a PDF, I have to add an empty comment, and then select 'no comments' in the print dialog.

This is really frustrating for me. When I open a new Writer document, the setting under `Tools` > `Options` > `LibreOffice Writer` > `Print` > `Comments` goes to **`In margins`** by default.

I have no idea why Writer has decided this should now be my default, and I would really love to know how to change this back to `None`.

Thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Please [edit] your post adding the version of libreoffice you are using. It could help people to search a solution for your problem. Did you ever change the [default template](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template)? Comments were buggy a long time ago, but it seems it was [fixed](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36815)...

Comment: I'm using version 4.4.1.2.

Thank you for the link - I never actively changed the template, but I have now created a new template with 'no comments' as the default setting, and set this as the default template. Seems to have solved the problem! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your default template was somehow changed.
You can fix creating a new template for the default page without the undesired features.

This is a way to do it:

- Open a new empty document
- `Tools` > `Options` > `LibreOffice Writer` > `Print` > `Comments` > **`None`**

Then follow the step-by-step procedure to change the default template from the wiki page of Libreoffice <sup>[[1](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template)]</sup>:

> - Choose File - Templates - Save As Template.
> - In the New Template box, type a name for the new template.
> - In the dialog that appears, double-click the "My Templates" folder, and then click Save. You will then be prompted for a name; write it
>     and click OK.
> - Choose File - New - Templates.
> - Double-click the "My Templates" folder.
> - Click on the template that you created, and click Set as Default.
> - Close the dialog.

Alternatively you can *purge* and install again Libreoffice, or hope that with the next major update the default template is overwritten, but I think to this is <sup>[[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100226)]</sup> *"to break a (butter)fly on the wheel"*.